# multiset/combination question

Tags: permutations, combinations, multisets

I have a bag full of: 7 green rocks, 12 yellow rocks, and 15
red rocks. How many ways are there to reach in and grab 4 rocks?

Is the answer 37C34 (37=7+12+15+4-1) or 6C3 (6=3+4-1)...or something else? By "C", I mean combination. This is a multiset problem as repeats are allowed and order doesn't matter.

Comment: Assume indistinguishability of like-coloured rocks. Let $x$ be the number of green we grab, $y$ the number of yellow, and $z$ the number o red. We want the number of solutions of $x+y+z=4$ in non-negative integers. You probably know how many there are.

Comment: So long as there are at least 4 of each colour, it doesn't affect the result. Or if the individual rocks are distinguishable, the colour doesn't matter in the slightest. No doubt a geologist would be amused at the assumption that rocks are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming rocks of the same color are indistinguishable, the number of ways of grabbing four rocks from the bag is equal to the number of solutions of the equation
$$g + y + r = 4$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $g$ is the number of green rocks, $y$ is the number of yellow rocks, and $r$ is the number of red rocks that are selected.  The number of solutions of the equation $g + y + r = 4$ in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways two addition signs can be placed in a row of four ones, which is 
$$\binom{4 + 2}{2} = \binom{6}{2}$$